# Unpause the game while the countdown timer goes off

Tags: c#, timer, unity-game-engine

I already made the game to pause and unpause by clicking escape button. Right now I want to when the game is paused and user clicking escape button again, the count down timer is ticking, and when the count down timer show the time reach 0, the game will be unpaused. The problem is when user clicks escape button again when the game is paused the count down timer is not ticking and the game unpauses immediately.

Here is the code so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

// Pause Logic
public class Pause : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public static bool paused = false; // For checking whether the game is paused or not

    float seconds = 5;
    float minutes = 0;

    void Update()
    {
        // If user hit escape button
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("escape"))
        {
            // Set the paused to togglePause method
            paused = TogglePause();
        }

    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        // If paused is true
        if (paused)
        {
            // Show the Paused GUI Box
            GUI.Box(new Rect(Screen.width / 3 - 5, Screen.height - 30, 450, 25), "Paused, Press Escape button again to unpause");
        }

    }

    bool TogglePause()
    {
        // If the time scale is 0 or pause
        if (Time.timeScale == 0.0f)
        {
            // Set time scale to 1
            Time.timeScale = 1f;

            // and set to the false
            return (false);
        }

        // If the time scale is 1 or unpause
        else
        {
            if (seconds <= 0)
            {
                // Set time scale to 0
                Time.timeScale = 0.0f;

                if (minutes >= 1)
                {
                    minutes--;
                }

                else
                {
                    minutes = 0;
                    seconds = 0;
                    GameObject.Find("Pause").guiText.text = minutes.ToString("f0") + ":0" + seconds.ToString("f0");
                }
            }

            else
            {
                seconds -= Time.deltaTime;
            }

            if (Mathf.Round(seconds) <= 9)
            {
                GameObject.Find("Pause").guiText.text = minutes.ToString("f0") + ":0" + seconds.ToString("f0");
            }

            else
            {
                GameObject.Find("Pause").guiText.text = minutes.ToString("f0") + ":" + seconds.ToString("f0");
            }

            return (true);
        }
    }
}
```

Your answer will be much appreciated.

Comment: In `TogglePause` you comment that the initial `if-else` should have the condition defined by `paused` as part of the conditional. Should this be included in the conditionals or should it not be included in the comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are setting timescale to zero. Therefore you need to be creative when keeping track of time after that. Time the duration yourself using: [Time.realtimeSinceStartup](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-realtimeSinceStartup.html).

```
private IEnumerator Pause(int p)
{
    Time.timeScale = 0.1f;        

    float pauseEndTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup + 1;

    while (Time.realtimeSinceStartup < pauseEndTime)
        yield return 0;

    Time.timeScale = 1;
}
```